# How to make breadcrumbs navigation on 'show' page for piece?

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I made breadcrumbs navigation as in this [tutorial](https://apostrophecms.org/docs/tutorials/getting-started/building-navigation.html#breadcrumb-trails). I use pieces for the catalog purposes and use 'index' and 'show' pages. Breadcrumbs navigation doesn't  work on 'show' page of the piece.
Is it possible to use Breadcrumbs navigation on 'show' page of the piece and how?

PS: The problem is that navigation element for 'index' page is not auto created on 'show' page.

Comment: Doesn't work how? Is it that you're getting everything BUT the last item, e.g. the show page that you are on?

Comment: @StuartRomanek , no. When I'm on the 'index' page, I see the correct navigation elements. When I go to the 'show' page, the 'index' page item is missing in the navigation. Pages 'index' and 'show' have the same code for navigation.

Comment: when you're on the show page, the details for show will be in `data.piece` and the data for the its parent index page will be in `data.page` .. To capture both in a show page you have to check for both in your breadcrumb building logic

Comment: @StuartRomanek, can you please give an example how to get info about 'index' page from data.piece or data.page on 'show' page? I searched through all the documents and questions on stackoverflow, but did not find how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should account for all ancestors and any piece/index page situation

```
  <nav>
    <ol>
      {% for item in data.page._ancestors %}
        <li>
          <a href="{{ item._url }}">
              {{ item.title }}
          </a>
        </li>
      {% endfor %}
      {% if apos.utils.isUndefined(data.piece) %}
        <li class="is-current">
          {{ data.page.title }}
        </li>
      {% else %}
        <li>
          <a href="{{ data.page._url }}"{{ data.page.title }}</a>
        </li>
        <li class="is-current">
          {{ data.piece.title }}
        </li>
      {% endif %}
    </ol>
  </nav>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Exactly what I need!

Comment: The only thing that: <a href="{{ data.page._url }}" **>** {{ data.page.title }}</a>